# Is there a way to check if the tab completion menu is open in ZSH

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion, zsh-zle

Is there a way to check if the tab completion menu is open in ZSH?

I am asking this question because I want to bind the space key to `accept-search` so that I can accept completion with the `space` key, but I want to do it in a way that doesn't interfere with the default behaviour of the `space` key (inserting the `space` character). Also, I want this because I don’t like that when I close the completion menu with `space` it inserts an space.

Someone in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/jkrt7e/zsh_accept_autocomplete_with_space/) helped me with this snippet, but I need a way to check if the autocompletion menu is open or not.

```sh
function space-or-accept-suggestion() {
  if <INSERT WAY TO CHECK IF AUTOCOMPLETION MENU IS OPEN>; then
    zle accept-search
  else
    zle self-insert
  fi
}

zle -N space-or-accept-suggestion
bindkey -M emacs ' ' space-or-accept-suggestion
```

Comment: You need to be clearer about what state you want to check for. As far as I can tell, what you describe is the default anyway. "autocompletion" as opposed to completion triggered by the tab key is usually only implemented via some plugin like autosuggestions. If you mean menu selection from the complist module is active, that uses the `menuselect` keymap so you can bind space differently for it. But by default, it'll be accepted and a space inserted.

Comment: Updated the question. It’s tab triggered completion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check that. Just use this:

```
zmodload zsh/complist
bindkey -M menuselect ' ' accept-search
```

More info can be found here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Menu-selection

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. For example, I type cd ~/ and press tab, select some option, and then press space and it still inserts the space. I think that maybe I should just adapt myself to the default behavior instead of trying to change it, even if only zsh doesn't want to work like that.

Comment: @DavidGuevara Sorry, I forgot you also need to do `zmodload zsh/complist` before using that `bindkey` command. I added it to my answer. Please try again.